Cookies not being stored in Production
The cookie was being stored when run on localhost however when hosted online the Cookie is not being stored on the Browser.
Below is my code for Backend:
const details= req.body;
    const result = await db.query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = $1',[details.username]);

    bcrypt.compare(details.password,result.rows[0].password,async(err,result)=>{
        console.log(result);
        if(result){
            const name=details.username;
            const token=jwt.sign({name},process.env.SESSION_SECRET,{expiresIn:'1d'});
            res.cookie('****',abcd);
            res.send(result);

        }
        else{
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }

Code for frontend:
const result = await fetch('https://mywebsite/login', {
method:'POST',
'credentials': 'include',
headers:{
'Content-Type':'application/json'
},
body:JSON.stringify(loginDetails),
    })


You need to configure cookie with secure and sameSite attributes.

How are you validating that cookies are not being stored? What is the value of the Set-Cookie header from his request?
